# How to query parameters in URL - json api

Tags: php, json, web-services, httprequest

I have to call api url to access the json object from it. in its tutorial, they provide some variables we can access through url, these variables have names different of the attributes name of the json object.

ex: url&parm1=val1

json object
{
  "parm1_name": "val1"
}

My question:

- How to return specific values depend on the attributes of the json object?
- Do we have to use the parameter names which are provided on their website?
- what the difference between "?pram1=val"  and **"pram1=:val"**
- How to query as we do in databases using greater or less than?

I use PHP and crul to retrieve the json object.

Comment: "How to return specific values depend on the attributes of the json object?" — No idea what you mean here.

Comment: "Do we have to use the parameter names which are provided on their website?" — How should we know if some documentation you haven't shared with us is providing examples or a comprehensive list?

Comment: "what the difference between "?pram1=val" and "pram1=:val"" — A colon. We have no way of knowing if the unspecified API you are using gives it any special meaning.

Comment: "How to query as we do in databases using greater or less than?" — Depends entirely on the API (about which you have told us nothing).

Comment: Your question to too broad. Avoid asking more than one question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

1. The value that each parameter/s return should be documented by the api and is up to the provider.
2. Yes, you have to use the parameters the api/website requires to return the value. If the api/website expects a value to return something then you have to provide the expected value. That also means the website will only recognize values that they look for.
3. The paramaters are key and value so

   - ?param=val1 => key "param" equals "val1"
   - ?param=:val1 => key "param" equals ":val1"
4. Unless the api provides a way to do then you can't. The limitations of what you can do is set by the api.

Api is essentially this:

```
<?php 
     // it gets ?id=val 
     // so if the GET parameters were ?id=1&name=blue&do=add
     // it would only recognize id parameters the other parameters wouldnt change a thing
     $val = $_GET["id"];
     if $val == 1 {
      return $data;
     }
 ?>
```

API must provide a way for you to e.g. search for "greater & less than" otherwise you cannot do it.